# SSJS date time filter for previous day

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, datetime

I'm having a problem in pulling in only the records with a ModifiedDate from the previous 24 hours from this SSJS filter when trying to access ListSubscribers object. I can use it to find a specific date range but would like to set this up nightly to pull with the above criteria. Have searched through this forum as well as the developer site with no luck. I have tried adding in the appropriate styling from the site but still nothing.

[https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_dateTimeNow.html](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/DateAdd.html)

Here is the code I'm trying to get to work but returns zero results in the data extension. The key is included in actual script but removed it on here for security purposes

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var targetDE = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx';       
    var logDE = DataExtension.Init(targetDE);
  
    function getListSubscriber(objectType, cols, filter) {
        var objectType = "ListSubscriber",
            cols = ["SubscriberKey", "Status", "ModifiedDate", "CreatedDate"],
            filter = { Property:"ModifiedDate", SimpleOperator:"greaterThan", Value:"DateAdd(Now(), '-1','D')" }
            moreData = true,
            reqID = null,
            numItems = 0;
        while (moreData) {
            moreData = false;
            var data = reqID == null ? prox.retrieve(objectType, cols, filter) : prox.getNextBatch(objectType, reqID);
            if (data != null) {
                moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
                reqID = data.RequestID;
                if (data && data.Results) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                        logDE.Rows.Add({
                            SubscriberKey: data.Results[i].SubscriberKey,
                            Status: data.Results[i].Status,
                            ModifiedDate: data.Results[i].ModifiedDate,
                            CreatedDate: data.Results[i].CreatedDate
                        });
                        numItems++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Write("<br />" + numItems + " total " + objectType + "<br>");
    }


    getListSubscriber(objectType, cols, filter)
    
} catch (e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```

Comment: The `"DateAdd(Now(), '-1','D')"` is not a JavaScript date, it's a string.  I'd suggest calculating your filter date in JavaScript and referring to the variable in your filter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and feedback. I'm still an SSJS noob, so would you declare the filter date in a different variable or does it go under an existing one?
Sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Adam Spriggs already mentioned, the date that you're printing is in a string. And i think you should pick the `DateValue` instead of the `Value`

**EDIT**
Not sure if the dateValue requires the leading `0` in your date field. That would be an adjustment to the `yesterday` functionality.

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {
    var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var targetDE = 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx';       
    var logDE = DataExtension.Init(targetDE);
  
    function getListSubscriber(objectType, cols, filter) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var yesterday = currentDate.getFullYear() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getDay() + 'T00:00:00';
        // yesterday should be `2022-04-12T21:19:18`
        var objectType = "ListSubscriber",
            cols = ["SubscriberKey", "Status", "ModifiedDate", "CreatedDate"],
            filter = { Property:"ModifiedDate", SimpleOperator:"greaterThan", DateValue: yesterday }
            moreData = true,
            reqID = null,
            numItems = 0;
        while (moreData) {
            moreData = false;
            var data = reqID == null ? prox.retrieve(objectType, cols, filter) : prox.getNextBatch(objectType, reqID);
            if (data != null) {
                moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
                reqID = data.RequestID;
                if (data && data.Results) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                        logDE.Rows.Add({
                            SubscriberKey: data.Results[i].SubscriberKey,
                            Status: data.Results[i].Status,
                            ModifiedDate: data.Results[i].ModifiedDate,
                            CreatedDate: data.Results[i].CreatedDate
                        });
                        numItems++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Write("<br />" + numItems + " total " + objectType + "<br>");
    }


    getListSubscriber(objectType, cols, filter)
    
} catch (e) {
    Write(Stringify(e));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample in the code, however when I run it automation studio no results show up in the data extension. Have even tried adding in the 0 to the date field with no luck.

Comment: And could you eliminate the fact that it might have something to do with timezones.
So for example temporary inject the date like; `2022-04-10T00:00:00`. And are you sure that you expect atleast more then 1 row to be returned?

Comment: Unfortunately that still does not produce any records. I'm wondering if it is something to do with data extension field being formatted to date/time making the filter not work.

Comment: And to make sure its related to the filter, could you then just add the date as a string like this;
`filter = { Property:"ModifiedDate", SimpleOperator:"greaterThan", Value: '2022-04-11' }
`

Comment: The problem is not the filter for a specific date but that I would like to automate this to pull in the records that have changed in the past 24 hours, 7 days, etc. So I'm left having to manually plug in ranges to avoid being timed out.